# How to remove the space between the children of an element with flex-wrap:wrap applied?

Tags: css, flexbox

The question is about `.text-wrapper`, which has `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap` applied to it. The reason for using `flex-wrap:wrap` is that otherwise `.text-wrapper` and `.tabs-wrapper` wouldn't stop being on one line, next to each other, like `inline` elements (*though I have no idea why, because `div`s should be `block` level elements, no? I'll appreciate if someone can enlighten me on this one as well*)

The problem is that I want the children of `.text-container` to its bottom, and not have more than 20px space between them.

But right now, there is a lot of space between `.text-wrapper` and `.tabs-wrapper`. How do I fix this?

**[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/xc6resfL/3/)**

OR

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.the-page {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}

.first-bottom {
    height: 100%;
}

.image-container img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.text-container {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 top:0px;
 position:relative;
 display:flex;
 align-items:flex-end;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.text-wrapper span {
 text-align:center;
 color:yellow;
}

.tabs-wrapper {
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:pink;
 opacity:0.5;
}

.tabs-wrapper-inner {
 height:100%;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 width:60%;
 margin:auto;
}

.tabs-wrapper-inner a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font:sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:red;
 padding:10px;
}

.other-content {
    background-color: purple;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-page">

<div class="first-bottom">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="http://photostry.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/highway-arizona-to-utah.jpg" />
    </div>
 
 <div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
   <span>SUN BEACH WARM</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-wrapper">
   <div class="tabs-wrapper-inner">
    <a href="#">AMY</a>
    <a href="#">BAMY</a>
    <a href="#">CAMY</a>
    <a href="#">DAMY</a>
    <a href="#">EAMY</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="other-content">.</div>

</div><!-- #the-page -->
```

Comment: wait, couldn't you just do `flex-direction:column;`?

Comment: @JacobGray Thank you. Removing `flex-wrap`, adding `flex-direction:column;`, adding `justify-content:flex-end`, and changing `align-items` to `align-items:center;` did it. Please write that as an answer so that I can accept it, that will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is about `.text-wrapper`, which has `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` applied to it.

I think you mean `.text-container`, because there is no `.text-wrapper` rule in your CSS.

> The reason for using `flex-wrap: wrap` is that otherwise `.text-wrapper` and `.tabs-wrapper` wouldn't stop being on one line, next to each other, like inline elements (*though I have no idea why, because divs should be block level elements, no? I'll appreciate if someone can enlighten me on this one as well*)

When you create a flex container – like you have by declaring `display: flex` on `.text-container` – you establish a [*flex formatting context*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). In this context, the children of the container become *flex items* and adhere to a *flex layout*, not a *block layout*. By default, flex items are aligned in a single, non-wrapping row (any block or inline `display` values are overridden by flex rules).

> The problem is that I want the children of `.text-container` to its bottom, and not have more than 20px space between them.
>
> But right now, there is a lot of space between `.text-wrapper` and `.tabs-wrapper`. How do I fix this?

To control the alignment of multiple lines in the cross axis, you can use the [**`align-content`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property) property.

The reason there is wide space between both lines is because the default value of `align-content` is `stretch`, which tells flex lines to distribute free space in the cross axis equally among themselves.

To better understand how this property works I would suggest you add a border (or background, or both) to `.text-wrapper` and `.tabs-wrapper`. Then try out the different `align-content` values: `flex-start`, `flex-end`, `center`, `space-between`, `space-around` and `stretch`.

Also, an important note to keep in mind, `align-content` only works when there are multiple lines in the cross axis of the flex container. If there is only one line it will have no effect, and you should use `align-items` instead.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.text-container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-end;
    align-content: flex-end; /* new */
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

To create a 20px gap between `.text-wrapper` and `.tabs-wrapper` simply add a bottom margin to `.text-wrapper`.

```
.text-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xc6resfL/5/)

---

To learn more about flexbox visit:

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You should use `flex-direction:column;` instead of `flex-wrap`.
For more information on `flex` and how to use it, there is [this excellent article at CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)